# problem of introducing long brackets in different lines

Tags: brackets

I have a problem writing an equation in `eqnarray` environment, where I split a single line into two lines. The first line starting with `\left[` and the second line ending with `\right]`, but I could not compile it using latex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: This should be as simple as ending the first line with `\right.`, and adding a `\left.` on the second line. If there are differences in vertical spacing between the lines, you'll need to use `\vphantom`. If you provide a small MWE we can adjust it for you.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `eqnarray`. See, *e.g.*, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197/586

Comment: For still another discussion of the weaknesses of the `eqnarray` environment (and hence why one shouldn't use it!), see Lars Madsen's essay "Avoid eqnarray!", published in the PracTeX Journal in 2006, available at http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `align` instead of`eqnarray` as per this question that compares [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align), and Stefan Kottwitz blong entry: [`\eqnarray` vs `\align` environment](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/eqnarray-align-environment/).

Here is an example of using the `\right.`, and `\left.` pair to complete the matching pair using the `align` environment.  Note that the size of the brackets is not the same in the first example. This is due to the fact that the `\left. <math> \right]` of the second line does not see the vertical spacing of the `\left[ <math> \right.` that the first line does. To fix that you need to add a `\vphantom{}` with the term which has the largest vertical spacing in the first line. This yields the second result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  y &= \left[\frac{1}{2}\right. \\
    &\qquad + \left.x^2+c\right]
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
  y &= \left[\frac{1}{2}\right. \\
    &\qquad + \left.x^2+c\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a little typo in the second line before the image: you wrote `\vpahantom{}`.

Comment: the style recommended in most "how to typeset math" manuals is to indent the lines starting with + by a couple of quads.  in the texbook, ch.19, dek uses \qquad in several such examples.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, have corrected that typo.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for pointing that out. Have added a `\qquad`.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to use the big-g delimiters instead of the `\left`, `\right` construct; using the big-g delimiters you don't have to worry for pairing the symbols in every line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= \biggl[ \frac{1}{2} \\
    &+ x^2 + c \biggr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `breqn` package.

instead of `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{equation*}`, use the environment `dmath` or `dmath*`.  the delimiters will be sized properly, and the line broken in an appropriate location.  there are also multi-line environments if your display needs them.

there are some limitations; for details, see the package documentation -- `texdoc breqn` if you have a tex live installation; otherwise, look on [ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf).

Comment: @barbaraL Out of curiosity, from the AMS submissions, do you know how frequently is `breqn` used _in the wild_.

Comment: @Aditya -- i've grepped for the package name in some of the files in current production, and didn't find it.  my guess is that it's not that well "advertised", and if an author isn't already using it when a book or paper goes into production here, the copyeditors are so used to the "old" methods of breaking lines that they just don't try it.  (it was still very much a beta when michael downes died, so it didn't get the exposure here that would have put it into the local toolbox.)

Comment: Thank you for the info. Hopefully the usage of breqn will slowly pick up.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `nath` class. It is not completely compatible with `amsmath`, but does provide its own multi-line math environments, which might be sufficient for simple math displays.

One of the features of `nath` is automatic delimiter scaling that works across multiple lines. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  y = \wall [ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \\
            + x^2 + c ] \return
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: I'd say that **nath** is *fully incompatible* with **amsmath**.

Comment: @egreg: The display math (`align` etc) and matrix commands (`bmatrix` etc), and extensible arrow from `amsmath` are incompatible with `nath`. Text mode commands (`\text`, `\dots`, `\cfrac`, `\binom`) work. It would have been much nicer if both packages had split their display math macros and other macros into separate packages which could be intermixed.

Comment: it's not completely true that `amsmath` is monolithic. there are several ancillary packages (which admittedly are automatically loaded by `amsmath`): `amsopn` (operator names), `amstext` (the `\text` facility) and `amsbsy` (bold symbols). (there's also `amscd`, but other packages serve that function better.)  any of these can be used without `amsmath`; whether or not they're compatible with `nath`, i don't know.  an overhaul of `amsmath` is tentatively scheduled for next year; `nath` is one of the non-ams packages on our list to look at, but i can't promise compatibilty after the overhaul.

Comment: Thanks @barbara. My guess is that compatibility with `nath` is difficult because `nath` changes a lot of TeX internals, like `breqn`. In some sense, like `breqn`, `nath` should be the one ensuring compatibility with `amsmath`; not the other way round. If `amsmath` could include some of the `nath` features ("correct" scaling of `\left` ... `\right` around operators with limits; an "intelligent" `\frac` macro (perhaps with a different name), automatic `\substack` if the subscript or superscript has multiple lines) that will be great.