# align inside \left ... \right

Tags: math-mode, align, bigdelim

I am trying to split an equation over multiple lines. To improve readability, I want to make the second line line up with the right side of the left brace of the first line as is almost achieved in the image below. Doing this, I stumbled upon the issue that alignment marks (`&`) do not work inside `\left`, `\right`. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278395/aligning-equations-across-multiple-lines-with-proper-left-and-right) question pointed me to the `\biggl` operators that circumvent this problem. I was however wondering: is there a way to make alignment marks inside `\left` and `\right` work as expected?

Example and code to generate it:

[image: example equation]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\leftside{\upsilon_{N, cw}(\omega)}
\def\prefix{- \frac{1}{\Delta} \Gamma}
\def\firstline{i\omega - \xi_{cc}\bar N + \frac{\Delta\Gamma}{2}}
\def\lastline{{+}\:\left.\frac{|\kappa|^2}{2\Delta\Gamma} \exp(-i\omega\tau)}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \leftside =& \prefix
            \begin{aligned}[t]
                &\left(\firstline\right.\\
                &\left.\lastline\right)
            \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might find it interesting to have a look at the documentation of the `mathtools` package (open a terminal emulator window and type `texdoc mathtools`): see bottom of p. 28 – p. 29.

Comment: Left... Right form a group, effectively hiding the & from align, thus will never work. Also using left right in the manner you do here is a bit dangerous, as the size depends on the content, thus you may end up with a ( that has a different size than ), therefore manual scaling is best in this case (as it is in general)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a solution with Sébastien Gouezel's  `\MTkillspecial` command and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command  from `mathtools`: I define a `\brkparens` command, which adds an implicit pair of `\left … \right` in its starred version. For fine tuning, the non-starred version accepts an optional argument (`\big, \Big`, &c.):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
   \newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\brkparens()
    \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\brkparens{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\def\leftside{\upsilon_{N, cw}(\omega)}
\def\prefix{- \frac{1}{\Delta} \Gamma}
\def\firstline{i\omega - \xi_{cc}\bar N + \frac{\Delta\Gamma}{2}}
\def\lastline{{+}\:\frac{|\kappa|^2}{2\Delta\Gamma} \exp(-i\omega\tau)}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \leftside =& \prefix
            \begin{aligned}[t]
                &\brkparens*{\firstline\\
                &\lastline}
            \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed: this is exactly what I was suggesting! :-)

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti: Actually, I've already given this kind of answer (maybe for braces), and it would have been more judicious to post a link in a comment, but I don't remember which question it was, nor when!

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of `\lastline` at line `7`, you have one unbalanced `\left.`, you should either remove this or remove the other one repeated at line `13`. Also, you may get rid of the `split` environment since the `\\` inside `aligned` will automatically split the equation over two lines.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\leftside{\upsilon_{N, cw}(\omega)}
\def\prefix{- \frac{1}{\Delta} \Gamma}
\def\firstline{i\omega - \xi_{cc}\bar N + \frac{\Delta\Gamma}{2}}
\def\lastline{{+}\:\frac{|\kappa|^2}{2\Delta\Gamma} \exp(-i\omega\tau)}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \leftside = \prefix & \left( \firstline \right. \\
                        & \left. \lastline  \right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You should probably been using `equation` instead of `align` in this specific case, since you are `align`ing nothing...

Comment: Yes, of course, I just kept the OP's format for easy comparison, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious, if the following simple elementary solution enabled by use of package `mathtools` fit to your expectation:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \begin{multlined}
\upsilon_{N, cw}(\omega) 
    = - \frac{1}{\Delta} \Gamma 
        \left(i\omega - \xi_{cc}\bar N + \frac{\Delta\Gamma}{2}\right.       \\
        \left. + \frac{|\kappa|^2}{2\Delta\Gamma} \exp(-i\omega\tau)  \right)
  \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing a `+` sign, it seems.

Comment: oh, error due to unaccurate copy-past ... added